# Vertically align text in horizontal plot legend containing expression

Tags: r, alignment, legend

When using an expression with bquote in a plot legend, the text following an exponent is not aligned vertically with the rest of the legend.

Example:

```
sometext <- 'bar'
e <- bquote(expression(.(sometext)^3~'Hello'))
plot(1)
legend('top',legend = c('foo', eval(e), 'world'), horiz = T, cex=0.9,xpd=T, bg='wheat')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of lines or fills, the answer is to not separate parts of the statement.  Where symbols are used in the legend this won't work.

```
plot(0)

e <- bquote(expression('foo'~~~.(sometext)^3~'Hello'~~~'world'))

legend('top',legend = eval(e), horiz = T, cex=1,xpd=T, bg='wheat')
```

[image]

As far as including symbols in the legend, this question remains unanswered.